# Reverse every 2nd word of a sentence

Tags: java, string

I am trying to reverse every 2nd words of every single sentence like

If a given string is :

```
My name is xyz
```

The desired output should be :

```
My eman is zyx
```

My current output is:

```
Ym eman s1 zyx
```

I am not able to achieve my desired output.Don't know what I am doing wrong here

Here is my code

```
    char[] sentence = "  Hi my name is person!".toCharArray();
    System.out.println(ReverseSentence(sentence));

}
private static char[] ReverseSentence(char[] sentence)
{
    //Given: "Hi my name is person!"
    //produce: "iH ym eman si !nosrep"

    if(sentence == null) return null;
    if(sentence.length == 1) return sentence;

    int startPosition=0;
    int counter = 0;
    int sentenceLength = sentence.length-1;

    //Solution handles any amount of spaces before, between words etc...

    while(counter <= sentenceLength)
    {
        if(sentence[counter] == ' ' && startPosition != -1 || sentenceLength == counter) //Have passed over a word so upon encountering a space or end of string reverse word
        {
            //swap from startPos to counter - 1
            //set start position to -1 and increment counter
            int begin = startPosition;

            int end;
            if(sentenceLength == counter)
            {
                end = counter;
            }
            else
                end = counter -1;
            char tmp;

            //Reverse characters
            while(end >= begin){

                tmp = sentence[begin];
                sentence[begin] = sentence[end];
                sentence[end] = tmp;

                end--; begin++;

            }

            startPosition = -1; //flag used to indicate we have no encountered a character of a string


        }

        else if(sentence[counter] !=' ' && startPosition == -1) //first time you encounter a letter in a word set the start position
        {
            startPosition = counter;
        }

        counter++;
    }

    return sentence;
}
```

Comment: I'm confused as to your requirements. So you want to reverse every other word? Please clarify exactly what it is that you're trying to do.

Comment: what is pattern here , you only want even position word to be reversed ?

Comment: As stated your question is unclear. There is ready library for this ( reversing a string - reverse method ) https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#reverse(java.lang.String) ? But no idea what you want to achieve. I have the same understanding of problem as MadConan

Comment: "Reverse a sentence" to me implies "The dog ate the world" becomes "world the ate dog The" or possibly "dlrow eht eta god ehT".   You should edit your title if that isn't what you want.

Comment: Adding to the confusion, there are also comments in your code that indicate the result you're getting is exactly what you want (`//produce: "iH ym eman...`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve your problem vary easy way! Just use a `flag` variable which will indicate the *even* or *odd* position, more precisely whether any word will gonna be reversed or not!

Look at the following modification I made in your code, just added three extra line:

```
private static boolean flag = true;// added a variable flag to check if we reverse the word or not.
private static char[] ReverseSentence(char[] sentence)
{
    //Given: "Hi my name is person!"
    //produce: "iH ym eman si !nosrep"

    if(sentence == null) return null;
    if(sentence.length == 1) return sentence;

    int startPosition=0;
    int counter = 0;
    int sentenceLength = sentence.length-1;

    //Solution handles any amount of spaces before, between words etc...

    while(counter <= sentenceLength)
    {
        if(sentence[counter] == ' ' && startPosition != -1 || sentenceLength == counter) //Have passed over a word so upon encountering a space or end of string reverse word
        {
            flag = !flag; // first time (odd position) we are not going to reverse!
            //swap from startPos to counter - 1
            //set start position to -1 and increment counter
            int begin = startPosition;

            int end;
            if(sentenceLength == counter)
            {
                end = counter;
            }
            else
                end = counter -1;
            char tmp;

            //Reverse characters
            while(end >= begin & flag){ //lets see whether we are going to reverse or not

                tmp = sentence[begin];
                sentence[begin] = sentence[end];
                sentence[end] = tmp;

                end--; begin++;

            }

            startPosition = -1; //flag used to indicate we have no encountered a character of a string


        }

        else if(sentence[counter] !=' ' && startPosition == -1) //first time you encounter a letter in a word set the start position
        {
            startPosition = counter;
        }

        counter++;
    }

    return sentence;
}
```

Input

> My name is xyz

Output:

> My eman is zyx

Comment: Thanks.Just need to change flag = true to flag = false

Answer (score 2):

If you want to reverse the alternate word you can try something like splitting the whole `String` into words delimited by whitespaces and apply `StringBuilder reverse()` on every second word like :-

```
        String s = "My name is xyz";
        String[] wordsArr = s.split(" "); // broke string into array delimited by " " whitespace
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i = 0 ; i< wordsArr.length; i++){ // loop over array length
            if(i%2 == 0) // if 1st word, 3rd word, 5th word..and so on words 
                sb.append(wordsArr[i]); // add  the word as it is
            else sb.append(new StringBuilder(wordsArr[i]).reverse()); // else use StringBuilder revrese() to reverse it
            sb.append(" ");// add a whitespace in between words
        }
        System.out.println(sb.toString().trim()); //remove extra whitespace from the end and convert StringBuilder to String
```

Output :- `My eman is zyx`

Comment: nvm, I guess in `if 1st, 3rd, 5th ..and so on words` you are counting from 1, not form 0 :)

Comment: @Pshemo actually I am pointing out the words, ie, 1st word 3rd word and so on, not the index ;)

Comment: BTW, you don't need to call `toString()` on `StringBuilder` to append it. `append` method accepts any `CharSequence`, not only `String`s (and StringBuilder implements CharSequence).

Comment: @Pshemo yeah, everytime i see your comment, there's a new thing to learn (y) :)

Comment: Also since Java 8  you can use `StringJoiner` instead of `StringBuilder`. This class is useful when you want to join some strings and place delimiter between them. So with `new StringJoiner(" ")` you can avoid using `append(" ")` and `trim()` (you will simply need to use `add` method instead of `append`).

Comment: that would be good in these kinds of scenarios, will look into that, but still i m working on Java 6  these days

Answer (score 0):

The following code does this "special reverse" which reverses any other word in the sentence:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String sentence = "My name is xyz";
    System.out.println(specialReverse(sentence)); //  My eman is zyx
}

private static String specialReverse(String sentence) {
    String result = "";
    String[] words = sentence.split(" ");
    // we'll reverse only every second word according to even/odd index
    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 1) {
            result += " " + reverse(words[i]);
        } else {
            result += " " + words[i];
        }
    }
    return result;
}

// easiest way to reverse a string in Java in a "one-liner"
private static String reverse(String word) {
    return new StringBuilder(word).reverse().toString();
}
```

Comment: It's generally helpful to include an explanation of your solution, rather than just a code dump.

Comment: @Michelle I agree with you on that one, though this one is pretty self explanatory IMO. Added the explaining sentence. Further, code comments help explaining no less then text...

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness here's Java-8 solution:

```
public static String reverseSentence(String input) {
    String[] words = input.split(" ");
    return IntStream.range(0, words.length)
            .mapToObj( i -> i % 2 == 0 ? words[i] : 
                    new StringBuilder(words[i]).reverse().toString())
            .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
}

reverseSentence("My name is xyz"); // -> My eman is zyx
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.eg.str;

// Without using StringBuilder  
// INPUT: "Java is very cool prog lang"
// OUTPUT: Java si very looc prog gnal

public class StrRev {
    
    public void reverse(String str) {
        String[] tokens = str.split(" ");
        String result = "";
        String k = "";
        for(int i=0; i<tokens.length; i++) {
            if(i%2 == 0)
                System.out.print(" " + tokens[i] + " ");
            else
                result = tokens[i];
                
                for (int j = result.length()-1; j >= 0; j--)  {
                    k = "" + result.charAt(j);
                    System.out.print(k);
                }
                result = "";
        }   
    }
    
    

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        StrRev obj = new StrRev();
        obj.reverse("Java is very cool prog lang");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

//reverse second word of sentence in java
public class ReverseSecondWord {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    String s="hello how are you?";
    String str[]=s.split(" ");
    String rev="";
    
    for(int i=0;i<str[1].length();i++)
    {
    char ch=str[1].charAt(i);
    rev=ch+rev;
    }       
    str[1]=rev;     
    for(int i=0;i<str.length;i++)
    {
        System.out.print(str[i]+" ");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Reverse_alternate_word {
    public static String reverseWord(String str){  // input :  my name is rohit
        char ch;                                   // output : my eman is tihor
        String rev="";

        for(int i=0; i<str.length(); i++){
             ch = str.charAt(i);
             rev =ch + rev;
        }
        return  rev;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        String sentence=sc.nextLine();

        int count = 0;
        String arr[] = sentence.split(" ");
        for(int i=0; i< arr.length; i++)
        {
            if(i%2==1){
               String rev_word= reverseWord(arr[i]);
                System.out.print(rev_word+" ");
            }else{
                System.out.print(arr[i]+" ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).