# logic to reverse the even position words

Tags: java, java-8

```
Input: "I am a software tester"
Output: "I ma a erawtfos tester"
```

What I tried so far :

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class ReverseEvenWords {
    public static void main (String[]args)
    {
        String val = "";
        String val1="";
        String value="";
        String test="I am a software tester";
        String[] t = test.split(" ");
        System.out.println (Arrays.toString(t));
        int arr= t.length;
        System.out.println (arr);
        for (int i=0; i<t.length;i += 2)
        {
            for (int j=1; j<t.length;j += 2)

            {
                val1=(t[j]);
                value  =new StringBuilder(val1).reverse().toString();

                System.out.print ("*"+value);   
             }
            val=t[i];
            String Test =val;
            System.out.print (","+Test);
            }

 }
}
```

I am successfully able to reverse the even position string but I am not able to concatenate the position and  but I am not able to get desired output.

Comment: I think I used i=i+2

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reverse every 2nd word of a sentence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31594537/reverse-every-2nd-word-of-a-sentence)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure why you need inner loops

```
String test="I am a software tester";
String[] t = test.split(" ");

String val = "";
for (int i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {

    if (i % 2 == 1)
        val = val + new StringBuilder(t[i]).reverse().toString() + " ";
    else
        val = val + t[i] + " ";
}
val = val.trim();
System.out.println(val);
```

**Of course** using a StringBuilder than a String for val would be better

---

In Java 8, it can be simplified, using the [`String.join()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence...-) method:

```
String test = "I am a software tester";

String[] t = test.split(" ");
for (int i = 1; i < t.length; i += 2)
    t[i] = new StringBuilder(t[i]).reverse().toString();
System.out.println(String.join(" ", t));
```

Comment: Nice solution If I add ,                                                                                                       val = val + new StringBuilder(t[i]).reverse().toString() + ", ";val = val + t[i] + ",";                        I get leading and trailing commas . Can you please help me to remove commas as well.

Comment: @ScaryWombat Hope you're ok with my added Java 8 version.

Comment: Java 8 is fine for me . Can you please explain the solution using comments in program

Comment: @Andreas Of course, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think your loop should be like this

```
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    for( int i = 0; i < t.length; i += 1 )
    {
        if( i % 2 != 0 )
        {
            char[] word = t[i].toCharArray();
            String reverseWord = "";
            for( int k = word.length; k > 0; k-- )
            {
                reverseWord += String.valueOf( word[k-1] );
            }
            result.append( reverseWord ).append( " " );
        }
        else
        {
            result.append( t[i] ).append( " " );
        }
    }
    System.out.println( result.toString() );
```

Comment: Nice. I am not able to upvote as I have low points :(